# Term for trust in government regulations or laws

Tags: single-word-requests

While writing a scholarship today I was looking for a word that indicated a persons trust in government regulations or law.

For example:

> Person A's (word for trust in government regulations or laws) is well described by his day-to-day ethics.

I did some google searches, checked a couple online dictionaries but was unable to pull a word that worked in this context. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think such a word exists? Can you think of any word that mean trust in any particular sort of thing?  For example, what's the word that means trust in your car getting you where you need to go, or trust that you'll get over your current cold, or trust that what goes up must come down, or trust that people care what you're saying, or trust that your webcam's turned off, or trust that this too shall pass, or trust that you'll be dead in a hundred years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Allegiance** suits the given sentence, but it does not mean trust.
The question is asking for two different things, in my opinion.

> loyalty or commitment to a superior or to a group or cause.

[Allegiance](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=allegiance&oq=allegiance&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i60j0l3.2005j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: *Allegiance* by itself isn't automatically connected with the government. I agree that the question is not asking for one thing.

Comment: @tchrist  I can have _confidence_ in government but that does not fit the given sentence.